# call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '----------' not found or invalid function name

Tags: php, functions

```
class mafongroup_admin {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'mafongroup_admin_menu' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'mafongroup_admin_menu_function' ));
    }

    public function mafongroup_admin_menu(){
        if ( current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ){
            $page_title="MAFON GROUP";
            $menu_title="MAFON GROUP";
            $capability="administrator";
            $menu_slug="mafongroup_admin_settings";
            $function="mafongroup_admin_menu_function";

            $mafongroup_menu_page_creation_method    = 'add_menu_page';
            $mafongroup_submenu_page_creation_method = 'add_submenu_page';

            $theme_options = $mafongroup_menu_page_creation_method( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function,'dashicons-image-filter', '2.111111');
        }
    }

    public function mafongroup_admin_menu_function(){
        echo 'do something';
    }
}

new mafongroup_admin();
```

Why is calling this method gives me error-'call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'mafongroup_admin_menu_function' not found or invalid function name'

Could someone assist ?

Thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like your previous questions answer if you have called any class method you need to reference the class. So you need to replace this line

```
$theme_options = $mafongroup_menu_page_creation_method( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function,'dashicons-image-filter', '2.111111');
```

With this one-

```
$theme_options = $mafongroup_menu_page_creation_method( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, array( $this, $function ),'dashicons-image-filter', '2.111111');
```

So your above code will be like below-

```
class mafongroup_admin {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'mafongroup_admin_menu' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'mafongroup_admin_menu_function' ));
    }

    public function mafongroup_admin_menu(){
        if ( current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ){
            $page_title="MAFON GROUP";
            $menu_title="MAFON GROUP";
            $capability="administrator";
            $menu_slug="mafongroup_admin_settings";
            $function="mafongroup_admin_menu_function";

            $mafongroup_menu_page_creation_method    = 'add_menu_page';
            $mafongroup_submenu_page_creation_method = 'add_submenu_page';

            $theme_options = $mafongroup_menu_page_creation_method( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, array( $this, $function ),'dashicons-image-filter', '2.111111');
        }
    }

    public function mafongroup_admin_menu_function(){
        echo 'do something';
    }
}

new mafongroup_admin();
```

Hope that helps.